# Perl cannot find and open existing file file name even I can print out exactly the same file name

Tags: perl

I'm having the following problem like this: 
I tried to traverse through all the sub-directory folders with numeric name, e.g.: 0/ 1/ 2/ ...
and try to check files named like this: combine_0_arc combine_1_arc ... in which the number in between is the same as the sub-folder name which this file exists, and here's how I do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

opendir(DIR, "./") or die "Failed to open directory: $!\n";
my @DirName = readdir(DIR) or die "Unable to read current directory: $!\n";
#closedir(DIR);

foreach (@DirName){
    chomp;
    my $CurrentDir =$_;
    next if ($CurrentDir eq ".");
    next if ($CurrentDir eq "..");
    if($CurrentDir =~ /^\d+$/){
    #    print "Iteration directory: $CurrentDir\n";
        opendir(SUBDIR, $CurrentDir) or die "Unable to read current directory: $CurrentDir\n";
        my @SubDirFiles =  readdir(SUBDIR);
        foreach (@SubDirFiles){
            chomp;      
  #          if($_ =~ /combine_0_arc/){next;}      
            if($_ =~ /combine_\d+_arc$/){
                my $UntestedArc = $_;
           #     print "Current directory: $CurrentDir\n";
           #     print `pwd`."\n";
           #     print "Combine_arc_name:$UntestedArc\n";
                open (FH, "<", $UntestedArc) or die "Cannot open file $UntestedArc:$!\n";
            }
          }
        }
```

It seems I'm getting the following error message: 
Cannot open file combine_0_arc:No such file or directory

and I tried to print out the folder name and the file name for each iteration it seems it's printing out correctly. I tried to chomp those trailing spaces or carriage returns for each file name or folder name but it seems it's not working. Can anybody explain me what's happening there? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please ignore the last missing enclosing bracket at the end. Looks like I'm missing with one when I copied my code here. And the level of directory I'm invoking my script is the root directory where it holds all sub-directories: 0/ 1/ 2/ ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [readir](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html) returns bare  file name, without the path.  So add it

```
foreach my $CurrentDir (@DirName) {
    # ...
    opendir my $SUBDIR, $CurrentDir;
    my @SubDirFiles = map { "$CurrentDir/$_" } readdir($SUBDIR);

    foreach my $untestedArc (@SubDirFiles) 
    {
        if ($UntestedArc =~ /combine_${CurrentDir}_arc$/) {
             # ...
        }
    }
}
```

where the regex uses *that* directory's name, not any number.

Notes

- `readdir` doesn't add a newline, no need to `chomp` (it doesn't hurt though)
- use lexical filehandles
- declare the loop variable (topicalizer) in the `foreach` statement

This answer assumes that your current working directory is the one with `@DirName` subdirectories.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your solution works out fine. I tried to call system command to change to current directory before but it failed. You guys are of great help. Thanks

Comment: Welcome. Changing the directory is indeed yet another way. Inside the loop over `@DirName` you say `my $old = cwd; chdir $CurrentDir;`. (Need `use Cwd;` for `cwd`.) Then `readdir`'s output (filenames without path) are the filenames in your current working directory, so then you don't prepend the directory name. But, you'll have to change the directory back at the end of the loop, `chdir $old;` All this assumes that your current working directory is the one with `@DirName` subdirectories

Comment: @王云龙 I corrected my previous comment, a piece of code was wrong. (`chdir` does _not_ return the current working directory before changing it.)  Just letting you know in case you intend to use it.

Answer (score 1):

`readdir` just returns the file names in the directory, i.e. the name relative to the directory given to the matching `opendir`. But, what you need for `open` is either the absolute name of the file or the name relative to the directory you are currently in (current working directory). Since `opendir` does not magically change the working directory (this could be done with `chdir`) the working directory is not the same as the directory scanned with `opendir` and thus the relative file you use within `open` can not be found within the current working directory.

Comment: Thanks buddy, I forgot there was "chdir" function. I tried `cd $DestinationFolder` before but looks like that way is not working.  This solved my doubts. Thanks a lot